# angular lib skip resolve npm package

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-library, ng-packagr

I have a angular lib and it is named 'ngx-qwe'.
The 'ngx-qwe' quote a npm package 'ngx-asd'.
The 'asd' package has build error when i build 'qwe'
I use 'ng build ngx-qwe --configuration production' to build 'ngx-qwe'

I want to skip resolve 'ngx-asd', how should I do?

"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.2.0",
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
"@angular/elements": "~9.1.4",
"ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",

try to change other builder, but not working